# Design circuits with unused inputs or has a constant expression

Tags: circuit-design, circuits, truth-table

I just started to learn about circuits design (without any prior experience), as a result I would like to ask a question.

**I was given a truth table for a circuit that has three inputs, and I need to design a circuit based on the truth table. However, after simplifying the expression, I found that one of the input is not used at all (That is to say, the expression only depends on the other two inputs). How can I draw a circuit that involves three entries but not using the first one at all?**

What if one of the expression is a constant, no matter what is the value of the circuit. How can I draw it?

I know I surely need to draw something, and surely I can't ignore that input because it is physically there. So I am not sure how to deal with it.

Comment: We call the entries "inputs" (and when you get to the other end the exits will "outputs".

Comment: If an input remains constant, it may be eliminated from the truth table. Only 2 inputs influence the output.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[image: schematic]

<sup>[simulate this circuit](/plugins/schematics?image=http%3a%2f%2fi.stack.imgur.com%2fHIKDS.png) – Schematic created using [CircuitLab](https://www.circuitlab.com/)</sup>

*Figure 1. Input C is "not connected".*

> And what about if the simplified expression is always 1 or 0 regardless of the state of these 3 inputs?

[image: schematic]

<sup>[simulate this circuit](/plugins/schematics?image=http%3a%2f%2fi.stack.imgur.com%2fr4ta9.png)</sup>

*Figure 1. Always high and always low could be represented by either of the centre or right layouts above.*

Comment: Thanks a lot!  And what about if the simplified expression is always 1 or 0 regardless of the state of these 3 inputs?

Comment: By the way, what is the software that you use to design circuits?

Comment: Welcome to EE.SE. You can create the schematic using the CircuitLab button on the editor toolbar. Double-click a component to edit its properties. 'R' = rotate, 'H' = horizontal flip. 'V' = vertical flip. 

Note that when you use the CircuitLab button on the editor toolbar and "Save and Insert" on the editor an editable schematic is saved in your post. That makes it easy for us to copy and edit in our answers. You don't need a CircuitLab account for Stack Exchange questions, so no screengrabs, no image uploads, no background grid.

Comment: See the update.

Comment: Oh okay thanks a lot! I appreciate your help, I don't know why I have not noticed that haha.